# Flutter: How to make custom shape textfields

Tags: flutter, textfield

Am new to this. How do I design the below:
a) a custom textbox to take inputs with icon

[image]

PS: Added issue when using InputBorder:

[image]

Comment: check `InputDecoration.border` property

Comment: but i doesnt allow me to draw the custom shape border around the textfield, or am I missing something?

Comment: see the existing classes that extend `InputBorder`

Comment: for example you can extend `OutlineInputBorder` and override its `paint` method

Comment: sure, your welcome

Comment: I still face one issue with this approach which is as follows:

When I use fillColor property on the TextBox it still fills as if its a rectangle (which is the default) and not as per the boundary.

I though the solution might be create my Own TextBox class which extends TextBox and then "draw the text baox shape myself" to avoid this issue, but in the TextBox class I cant find how to redraw the custom shape.

Any pointers please?

Comment: post your code then

Answer (score 2):

Finally as per the suggestions used the below:

```
class DMTextBoxOutlineBorder extends OutlineInputBorder {

  @override
    void paint(
      Canvas canvas,
      Rect rect, {
        double gapStart,
        double gapExtent = 0.0,
        double gapPercentage = 0.0,
        TextDirection textDirection,
      }) {

    var paint = Paint();
    paint.color = Colors.black;
    paint.strokeWidth = 1.0;

    var startXPos = rect.bottomLeft.dx;
    var startYPos = rect.bottomLeft.dy;
    var height =  rect.bottomLeft.dy - rect.topLeft.dy;
    var width = (rect.bottomRight.dx - rect.bottomLeft.dx);

    var textBox = Path();
    textBox.moveTo(startXPos, startYPos);
    textBox.lineTo(startXPos + width, startYPos);
    ......rest of the code to complete the required shape

    canvas.drawPath(textBox, paint);
  }

  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a textFormFeild and specify the decoration property . You need to use the prefixIcon property to add an icon for your textfeild.

```
TextFormFeild(decoration: InputDecoration(prefixIcon: //your icon),),
```

Comment: but i doesnt allow me to draw the custom shape border around the textfield, or am I missing something?

Comment: so for the icon its done and now you need to make the border ?

Answer (score 0):

Actually found a better way using ClipPath.

Comment: no, it is not a better way, see the following for example: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/JvxqHp6qgr/ and try to do the same thing with `ClipPath` - i have no idea why people here use `ClipPath` everywhere when `ShapeBorder` or `InputBorder` should be used...

Comment: Thanks @pskink

I guess my reason to say its easier can be one from my less experience with Flutter and second from the challenges I faced with Input border.
The primary issue being, I am able to make the border as per the above image as needed without a problem using InputBorder, but when I fill it say with a color (say red, to test), it still fills up a rectangle

(Edit: Added a photo to question now)

Comment: see `InputBorder.getOuterPath` method

Comment: Hi, I think more than the border the issue is about the area of the textBox container. No matter how the border is changed but there are areas which "Should not be " inside the textbox (new shape) are still, because all I am able to do by overriding the border is change the border to the desired shape but not the actual ""box"" of the Textbox from a rectangle to the desired Shape.

I tried making changes to the RenderBox, but couldnt success.

Comment: what `RenderBox`? override `InputBorder.getOuterPath`

Comment: That's done. But any changes to the Border only changes the visual appearance. However, the area that the "TextBox Widget considers to be a part of the TextBox is not changed by the Input Border and its methods".
Ref: in the picture above I am mentioning about the areas marked as 
a) The space which should be included in the textfield and is not
b) The space which should not be included in the textfield and is.